# Using VBA, I want to count how many times a string appears in specific column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table, with product ID alongside product Name (A and B respectively).
In a separate table (on the same sheet), I have product ID alongside customer. (O and P respectively). Some IDs have multiple customers. Hence, the same ID can appear multiple times.

For each cell in column A, is there a way to count how many times the string appears in column P. And then, print in next to the cell in question in column C?

This is the code I've written thus far but kind of stuck now:

```
Sub CountOccurrences()

Dim ID As String
Dim Result As Long
'Result refers to the number of times it is found in column P 
Dim tablerng As Range
'The table consisting of columns O  and P 
Dim resultsrng As Range 
Dim LastRow As Long 
Cell As Range 
LastRow= Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set tablerng = Range("P1:P" & LastRow)
Set resultsrng = Range(“C1:C”& LastRow)
For Each cell In tablerng
```

Not sure what do do from here...

Comment: Why use VBA?  A simple COUNTIFS will do what you want: `=COUNTIFS(O:O,A2)`

Comment: Just to get in some practise. Very new to VBA . Thank you for the response though.

Answer (score 1):

Depending how you want to handle your data, determining your phrase/string to find, something like this would work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub instancesOfString()
    Dim catchPhrase As String
    catchPhrase = InputBox("What is the string to match?")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim dataArray As Variant
    dataArray = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).Value
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If dataArray(i, 1) = catchPhrase Then
            Cells(i, 2).Value = 1
            Dim catchPhraseCount As Long
            catchPhraseCount = catchPhraseCount + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print catchPhraseCount
End Sub
```

High level points are:

- Inputbox used to determine the desired string
- Capture your data as an array to help with speed
- Input the value "1" to the adjacent cell when matched
- Perform a count of matched strings within the loop
- Output the total count to the immediate window

This would teach you a few things as you go, e.g., referencing/using the immediate window, working with loops, and working with arrays... I tried to pack as many high-level things into the small package, since you mentioned you were doing this to learn.

Spend some time, dissect the items, and you could pare this down to less lines, even removing the need for the "check" value in the adjacent cell, changing the final output...

---

From what you have in your initial code, we don't know where you find the input, you start a loop, but would need to understand how you intend to use the `for each` aspect, nor do we know for what some of the variables are being used.  Until those are taken further, there isn't much that can be done to help with your starting point beyond providing a code, which isn't really the goal here (though obviously I just did that)...

The use of fully-named variables is significant and helps with the understanding, so you're well on your way!

Answer (score 1):

Before we begin, I strongly recommend [`Option Explicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) This goes at the very top of each VBA module and will tell you if you have any undeclared variables

Before I even ran your code to do other things with it, there was no `Dim` before `Cell As Range` and in `Set resultsrng = Range(“C1:C” & LastRow)` you had quotation marks that VBA didn't like resulting in a compile error `Set resultsrng = Range("C1:C" & LastRow)` is what VBA will work with

Now on to the possible ways to count the occurrences of a string in VBA

This will get only count if the ID is exactly equal to, this is case sensitive

```
For Each Cell In tablerng
    If Cell.Value = ID Then
        Result = Result + 1
    End If
Next Cell
```

To get the count of the string ignoring case sensitivity you can change it all to lower or upper case, using `UCase()` or `LCase` on both side of the If statement

```
For Each Cell In tablerng
    If UCase(Cell.Value) = UCase(ID) Then
        Result = Result + 1
    End If
Next Cell
```

And lastly to check if a cell contains the string you are after you can use [`Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) with wild cards

```
For Each Cell In tablerng
    If Cell.Value Like "*" & ID & "*" Then
        Result = Result + 1
    End If
Next Cell
```

Bonus option, as Scott Craver mentioned in the comments you can use `=COUNTIFS(O:O,A2)` [both in VBA and out of it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction)